# an alternative for FILESTREAM feature in SQLserver on docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, memory-management, .net-core, containers

I am using SQLserver 2019 on docker. I want to store files (pdf, jpg...) between 1-10 MB in the database. I am familiar with the FILESTREAM feature in SQLserver on windows, but it is not supported in the containers.

I have some plans for working with saved files, for example, I am going to search for some specific text in the pdf files in the future and I am worried about memory usage and related problems.

Do you have any alternatives for the FILESTREAM feature in SQLserver on docker?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you need the added transactional guarantees of `FILESTREAM`? If not, just having clients store the files on their own volume (which you could expose from the container as an SMB file share) and recording the (relative) path in a character column may be enough. You do need to back them up separately from the database in that case, but if you're running the engine in a container you need a separate backup strategy anyway.

Comment: thank you @JeroenMostert, you mean the files should be ONLY saved in the client's hosts?? I have an agent that store files and clients can access them just by using that. I think I should save my files on the server.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about saving files on the server. With `FILESTREAM`, you'd be streaming them to SQL Server to have them stored on the local file system; I propose you instead store them on a file share (exposed through the containerized server if possible), which is still initiated by the clients, but not stored on the clients. Basically, implement what `FILESTREAM` does yourself with a share, which is what people did before `FILESTREAM` existed. It may be more convenient to do this with a second container than to add file server support to the SQL container, though.

Comment: If you're going to add searching to what are basically generic binary blobs for SQL Server, you probably want something dedicated to that anyway, like Lucene. `FILESTREAM` cooperates with full-text search, but without it the engine basically won't help you. If you're going top set up a big server this way, consider not using a container at all and just dedicating a full machine (whether physical or virtual), as that doesn't play very well with containerization.

Comment: Ok, thanks @JeroenMostert, I will try some of these ways and let you know about the results...